# Set macOS screensaver from command line in macOS 14 Sonoma

Tags: command-line, mac, screensaver

In earlier versions of macOS, I was able to set the screensaver from a shell script using a command like this:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver moduleDict -dict moduleName Drift path /System/Library/Screen\\ Savers/Drift.saver type 0
```

In macOS 14, however, it seems like while the system still *writes* to that property, setting the property no longer controls the screensaver. You can read the property via

```
defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver
```

But setting it doesn't change the selected screensaver.

How can I programmatically control which screensaver is selected in macOS 14 Sonoma?

Answer (score 0):

In Ventura, I was using `killall cfprefsd` in my scripts after changing the `SelectedFolderPath` key of `com.apple.ScreenSaverPhotoChooser`, the change was immediate.

However in macOS 14 Sonoma, that is not enough. It does eventually change the setting if I also update the `CustomFolderDict` dictionary value at the same time,
although it may take a few minutes for the change to be reflected in the running screensaver.

Opening System Settings to Screensaver will show the correct folder name (and I assume the correct path underneath the UI), but the preview's cache may be delayed until whatever other process refreshes with the above set `CustomFolderDict` key.

Here is the script I'm using to debug the behavior, being run when the shell is in the directory to be changed to (`pwd`):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# write the SelectedFolderPath key
/usr/bin/defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ScreenSaverPhotoChooser SelectedFolderPath "$(pwd)"

# write the new CustomFolderDict key
/usr/bin/defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ScreenSaverPhotoChooser CustomFolderDict -dict identifier "$(pwd)" name "$(pwd | perl -pe 's/.*\///gmi')"

# restart cfprefsd to pickup the change (required in ventura)
killall cfprefsd

# did we write what we expected to?
/usr/bin/defaults -currentHost read com.apple.ScreenSaverPhotoChooser

# launch screensaver to test
open /System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app --background

# did anything change after screensaver launched?
sleep 5
/usr/bin/defaults -currentHost read com.apple.ScreenSaverPhotoChooser
```